# Tor & cURL: Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0

Tags: curl, centos, tor

Was running a scraping script on one server using tor, and all worked fine. Moved it to the production server and the script stopped working. Tried running cURL manually, and got the following output:

```
curl http://www.google.com --socks5 '127.0.0.1:9050'
curl: (7) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (6)
```

Relevant info:
Tor version 0.2.2.35 |
CentOS 6.2 i686

```
curl --version
curl 7.19.7 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.12.7.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

There doesn't seem to be much info on this particular error message that I could find in my searching, just generic bad configurations or tor not running. I am using the same configuration on my production server as the development server where it worked.

Comment: Finally found a solution, if anyone else has this problem. Turns out the system clock was 3 hours behind. Once I installed ntp and synced it up, tor works fine.

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question and accept it. This makes it easier for people with the same issue to find the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The time on my server was 10 hours behind. After fixing it (ntpd already was installed, I just ran command */usr/sbin/ntpdate 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org europe.pool.ntp.org*) and restarting Tor, everything works.